# Swing - How to close a form from inside? How to close the form without affecting the parent form?

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

I am creating a form in Swing toolkit.
When I want to close it, I go to the JFrame and set it to visible false.
Since the frame creates a Java class of the form, I can easily do it from outside.

When I have a cancel button I usually send a listener inside the form that calls the outer:

```
 Jframe.setVisible (false)
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these if you do not need to code much!
[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TY73.png)

Comment: Thank you Robert ;some typos!

Answer (score 5):

The `SwingUtilities` class provide a method to get the window ancestor of a given component.
You can gat the parent Window and call `setVisible` or `dispose` or perhaps only an event.

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
window.setVisible( false );
    // OR
window.dispose();
    // OR
WindowListener[] windowListeners = window.getWindowListeners();
windowListeners[0].windowClosing( null );
```

Comment: I would advise against option #3 that looks like a trick rather than standard code in Swing. I am not even sure that it would work correctly in all scenarios.

Comment: of cause it's a risky hack, for eg. JToolBar floating dialog